# Why passive light v is defective?

Tags: minimalism, passive

In Chomsky (2000,2001), the passive, along with unaccusative and other forms of participle object constructions, with the light *v* is considered 'defective' because as Chomsky (2001:6) says: light *v* of a passives lacks:
1. The ability to assign Accusative Case;
2. This inability results from not having a phi-complete bundles, in fact only [person] is valued after the light *v* probes. That's why the DP object in passive sentences has to move for Nominative Case assigning in T and complete the phi-agreement features there.

What remains mysterious for me is not this movement for Nom Case, neither the defective nature, but I have data in which both a Transitive Active *v* has the same phi-features exhibited on this 'defective' light *v* of the passive. Those who are familiar with Phase Theory in the minimalist program, please help me understand more this 'defectiveness notion' in the light of passives.

Comment: Not sure what you find “mysterious” about it. Could you explain more what kind of data you have?

Comment: It may be a simple confusion of the linguistic term _defective verb_ (meaning "a verb with an incomplete conjugation, or one which cannot be used in some other way as normal verbs can", to quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb)), and the more common, non-linguistic sense of "defective" meaning "not correctly designed or made; damaged". Chomsky clearly meant the grammatical sense, because he uses lacks for arguments. There's nothing overtly defective; there can't be, because light _v_ is a non-terminal.

Comment: The mysterious thing I find is the correlation between inability to assign Accusative Case and the Phi-features:[person],[number],[gender]. For example in 'The city was destroyed by the army', the internal argument 'the city' must move for Case, because the passive cannot match this feature because it's defective, this is my question, on what grounds this correlation between Case and Phi is established.

Comment: The data I have are from Berber, in the active voice we say: 'carz-x ijja' 'I plowed the land', 'carz-x ijjan' 'I plowed the lands', in the Passive, this agreement system (Phi-features) remain the same, they don't become defective to mean that the head v is defective and we say, 'ytwacarz ijja' and 'twacarz-n ijja-n' respectively. I have the whole paradigm of data, but the space here is narrow to present them in a systematic way. Now if the light v is defective (it lacks a feature of agr) and that's why the passive is defective, how can we account for this issue with the data here..

Comment: Perhaps you can't. These theories are very abstract and are not based on data as much as faith. If you lack faith, they often don't work.

Comment: I see. Hint: are those features interpretable or uninterpretable?

Comment: jlawler, to a great extent that's what I started to believe in recently, so you're totally right. I have articles written about this issue in which there's no single piece of data explored, only theory and conceptual architecture.

Comment: Alex B. The ones on the light v head are uninterpretable, and the ones on the DP objects are Interpretable (in fact, fully specified for both Phi & Acc Case). At the first sight, Chomsky's correlation is very reasonable, at least it proves why the DP object of Active surfaces as a DP subject (Surface Subj) of the passive. What's at stake here, however, as far as I know, is that the correlation of Chomsky (2001) between Case and Phi to be defective is found in participles taking forms of adjectivals. The data I have prove quite the opposite. I have 1 solution: separate Case from Phi.